# Morris.js won't draw graph in my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, morris.js

Learning rails by making a project. Trying to build a graph form @resource.prices data. Have been following rails cast about it. Doing everything just the way it shows but having no result in here.

Here's the coffeescript I have:

```
jQuery -> 
  Morris.Line
    element: 'prices_chart'
    data: $('#prices_chart').data('prices')
    xkey: 'date'
    ykeys: ['price']
    labels: ['Price']
```

Here's the piece of my view file code:

```
<%= content_tag :div, "", id: "prices_chart", data: {prices: @resource.prices} %>
```

Here's what @resource.prices.inspect gives out:

```
    #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [
#<Price id: 5, resource_id: 8, price: 13, created_at: "2015-12-30 11:59:38", updated_at: "2015-12-30 11:59:38", date: "2015-01-07">, 
#<Price id: 6, resource_id: 8, price: 14, created_at: "2015-12-30 11:59:53", updated_at: "2015-12-30 11:59:53", date: "2015-02-05">, 
#<Price id: 7, resource_id: 8, price: 15, created_at: "2015-12-30 12:00:03", updated_at: "2015-12-30 12:00:03", date: "2015-03-26">,
...]>
```

As we can see it contains both price and date. But the graph is still empty. What may be wrong? And what are the three dots at the end of array?

**UPD** There's an error in console pointing to morris.js: 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it points out, you seemed to have the wrong way to pass your data, check the `data-price` attribute of '#prices_chart' in html console and you will see something like: `"#<ActiveRecord::Associations..."`, it not a JSON array and of course it can't be working.

A workaround for your situation is passing your `@prices` as JSON string:

```
<%= content_tag :div, "", id: "prices_chart", data: {prices: @resource.prices.to_json } %>
```

However, the more elegant way to do that is using ajax to fetch your data in JSON

```
jQuery -> 
  $.ajax
    url: # your api endpoint
    data: # your data
    success: (data) ->
      Morris.Line
        element: 'prices_chart'
        data: data
        xkey: 'date'
        ykeys: ['price']
        labels: ['Price']
```

It's up to you to choose the most appropriate way, good luck!

Comment: BTW, that ... thing comes out because of using .build function for one of the forms on the same view. Worked it arund by calling chart earlier than .build function.